# How to show my PWA on desktop browser as mobile app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA which is developed in Ionic 3. Now it's working fine on mobile and tablets perfectly and desktop browser as well.

Now my query is when I run it on desktop browser it shows on full screen. So instead of showing full screen I need to show as mobile app i.e. center of the screen.

I can give link button on that page if user want to continue with desktop site.

example site for your ref. : https://infinity.icicibank.com/corp/AuthenticationController;jsessionid=0000BP6Q_9NOSldGNL-ae82llVM:R422963ue?bwayparam=N15frMp4TsS%2B1fi64yNCsA%3D%3D

it's shows in center of page in desktop browser and option with desktop browser.

How can I achieve this?

I tried to do with CSS media query but it fails because if request is coming from desktop browser then it show's site in full screen.

Comment: Hey man, so how did you solve this issue? I would love to learn how to achieve that (centrify pwa built in ionic). This: m.icicibank.com looks awesome

Comment: What I tried is to wrap ion-app in a dive and do something like this: https://codepen.io/cmer41k/pen/MLOVwr but Ionic still overrides flexbox rules and I can't centralyze the app still.

Comment: I think I figured it;) <ion-app style="position: relative;margin: auto;top: 0;bottom: 0; max-width: 1024px">
  </ion-app>

Comment: I have solved it using media queries in css as per the screen size. i just did work around I don't know this is right or wrong.

Answer (score -2):

Do you want to show your app in your mobile browser as like it's on the downloaded app or would you like to show it on your desktop as like it's the app?

Your reference example is not available in the moment.

If I understood you right you have to work with @ionic/angular `Platform` so you can choose if you are on mobile or not and then choose which css to pick.

Comment: Hi Yingrjimsch,


[Datta] : I want to show it on desktop browser as like it's app in center. 

[Datta] : You can click on this URL : https://m.icicibank.com it will redirect to that page. We want exactly this for our PWA.

[Datta] : yes @ionic/angular platform , but how to choose mobile CSS on desktop browser request

[Datta] : Yes, We need to show a mobile app view in desktop web browser.

Comment: If you want it to look like an app you cann press F12 in Chrome to open Chrome DevTools after that you can click Ctrl + Shift + M. Whit this setting you can see how it would look like on a Phone.
I hope this helps

Comment: I have figured out this problem with CSS and media queries. you can visit this link on your desktop browser. m.icicibank.com  I wanted to show exactly like this.

Comment: Good to here. If my answer helped you please mark it as the right answer and vote it up :D